# Why did my rebase add commits to the history of my dev branch, but not actually rebase onto main?

Tags: git, github, open-source, rebase

I am working on an open source project and have a clone in my git repo that I work off of. I started a dev branch (off my clone) off the main branch and have been working on the code for a few days. I have finished with my changes and am now ready to open a pull request to the main repo from my dev branch.

I believe I followed the following steps, but now I'm not sure and I don't know how to fix it:
I synced my main `main` branch (on my clone) with the source repo's `main` branch and then ran `git rebase main` from my dev branch. I went through the merge conflicts and resolved them, but once that was finished I was unable to run `git push` and was prompted to `git pull` again. I ended up doing that and then had to rebase yet again. I went through that a second time, but after finishing that, my branch isn't actually rebased onto main. Instead, it has the commits from main in its history, but is still its own branch and my local commits are in the history twice (see below). I seem to have made a mistake somewhere, but I don't know where and I don't know how to fix it. Any help would be greatly appreciated! (even if it's just directing me to a similar question--I couldn't figure out good search terms to find anything helpful).

Example `git log --oneline --graph --all` (ignore the hashes, they are all unique on the actual git log):

```
* 8f29 (HEAD -> metadata, origin/metadata) add metadata_filename to ppt partition
* ef6d add metadata_filename to epub partition
* 26a2 add metadata_filename to email partition
* feat: extract extra metadata
* ec40 fix malformed pptx issue
* 5bf7 fix: remove fake api key
* a9b9 feat: partition_tsv for tab separated value files
* 8f29 add metadata_filename to ppt partition
* ef6d add metadata_filename to epub partition
* 26a2 add metadata_filename to email partition
| * 4ea7 (origin/main, origin/HEAD, main) feat: extract extra metadata
| * ec40 fix malformed pptx issue
| * 5bf7 fix: remove fake api key
| * a9b9 feat: partition_tsv for tab separated value files 
|/
* a9b9
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you for sure what happen without your `git reflog`, but here's how you can fix it.

You need to reset your `metadata` branch to the point it was before you tried to merge `main`. It's important to note that the hashes I'm about to say should be the ones in your log and not the ones you provided since they aren't unique here.

Make sure you have your `metadata` branch checked out.

1. `git reset --hard 8f29`, this hash needs to be the older of the `8f29` commits you listed.

Always try to rebase off of the remote specs. This way you don't have to worry about updating local branches when you fetch.

2. `git rebase origin/main`

Force push your corrected branch.

3. `git push --force origin metadata`

Done. Now you can create a PR that is based off the latest `main` branch.

A side note: when working with forks you usually have an `upstream` remote that points to the original repo. With that you can fetch the upstream and then rebase onto `upstream/main` and not worry about having to sync your `origin/main` to the original repo.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up squashing and then rebasing again. I think my mistake was running `git pull` before instead of just doing a force `push`